# User Profile Synchronization Service not started in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

We have facing the problem in our SharePoint 2010 “This User Profile Application's connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or User Profile Service may not have been started. Please contact your administrator.” recently. We have restarted our SharePoint server 2010 recently and once after that we faced this problem. Due to this we are unable to view the user profiles and add new user details. As checked the solution and I have tried the following things but the issue is not yet resolved in our server. Any suggested solution will be grateful for me to resolve this issue.

1.I have started “User Profile Synchronization service” under “Manage Services on Server” from Central Administration.

2.” User Profile Synchronization service” struck in “Starting” status itself and hence the following services are not started and hence in disabled status.

Forefront Identity Manager Service

Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service

3.I have tried to create a new Farm account and started “User Profile Synchronization service” but faced the same problem.

Thank you and Best Regards,

Ragunaathan M P

[User Profile Service Application - Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0sGE.jpg)

[User Profile Synchronization Service Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UTpB.jpg)

Comment: can you make sure that Forefront Identity Manager Service & Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service has start type "automatic"? Once done, try to start User Profile Synchronization service.

Comment: thanks for the update. I have tried to set the FIM services start up type as "Automatic" but the same issue I have faced.i.e. User Profile Synchronization service struck in Starting status.

Comment: can you check in event viewer for any error message?